# Парсинг Facebook постов любого пользователя

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Задача: имеется список людей с Facebook , мне нужно получить все его посты на стенке. Что лучше использовать ? API Graph или же какой-нибудь другой способ? 
Если можно с примером, трудно понять с чего начать нужно.
И зачем приложение регистрировать ?

Comment: нашел решение ? :) У меня в 2019 стоит точно такая же задача - подскажите плиз решение..